# Silverstripe not working on Plesk Server

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am trying to create a new domain which runs on SilverStripe 3.0. I am unable to figure out the issue. If I upload a custom php page then it runs fine, but my website is not working. It shows blank page but shows the favico.

If I try to open up `www.mydomain.com/admin/`, I get the error

`Page Not Found
The requested URL /admin/pages was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

This is not a Silverstripe error page. Here is my php info [Info](http://ezb2706.info/info.php)

Please let me know if I am missing something or there is any way to figure out the issue.

Comment: seems like the main .htaccess is missing on your machine?

Comment: @wmk .htaccess is there inside public_html where it should be

Answer (score 2):

Try www.yourdomain.com/index.php/admin

If that works then it is because your rewrites are not working. This can be because .htaccess isn't configured properly, or because .htaccess is not used at all (in which case you need to edit your server config).

Last I used Plesk it always used apache. If that is different now and you're using nginx as more than a forward proxy, then you will need to set up the redirects for your site manually.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like your .htaccess is not being respected. Does Plesk allow overrides for .htaccess in the local directory?

At an apache level we would have something like this stanza to ensure the the .htaccess of the project was respected;

AllowOverride All

If your .htaccess is being processed, make sure that your host has mod_rewrite enabled as that is required to access to pretty URLS.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled. How to make use os AllowOverride All ?